# React/Node.js Personal Website Not Updating Content on Firebase Deployment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, deployment, build

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am currently working on a personal website using React for the front end and Node.js for the back end. My goal is to set up a deployment pipeline and host it on Firebase Hosting. However, I'm encountering an issue where the content on the website is not updating as expected after each deployment.

Here's an overview of my setup and the steps I've taken:

I have a React application for the front end and a Node.js server for the back end.
I am using Firebase Hosting for deployment.
I have set up a GitHub repository for version control.
My pipeline is triggered automatically on every push to the main branch.
The problem is that when I make changes to the content of my website, such as modifying text or adding new features, the changes do not seem to reflect on the deployed website, even though the deployment pipeline runs without errors.

Here are some things I've already checked:

I've verified that my code changes are successfully pushed to the main branch on GitHub.
The Firebase deployment process appears to complete without errors, and I can see the deployment logs.
I've cleared my browser cache to ensure that I'm not seeing cached content.
Additionally, I have tried using the needs keyword in my YAML file to ensure proper order and dependencies between jobs in my CI/CD pipeline.

Here's a simplified version of my .github/workflows/pipeline.yml file:

```
# This file was auto-generated by the Firebase CLI
# https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on merge

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  checkout_code:
    name: Checkout code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

  build_code:
    name: Build code
    needs: checkout_code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Install dependecies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Build
        run: npm run build

  deploy_to_firebase:
    name: Deploy to Firebase
    needs: build_code
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting
        uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: "${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}"
          firebaseServiceAccount: "${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KALOYAN_PORTFOLIO }}"
          channelId: live
          projectId: MY_PROJECT_ID
```

Can anyone provide insights or suggestions on what might be causing this issue and how to ensure that my content updates are reflected on the deployed Firebase website?

Thank you in advance for your help!